# <progress> Object not Displaying in HTA (with IE11 Install)

Tags: html, progress-bar, hta

Pretty basic question, can someone tell me why the example code for the progress bar element would work fine in all three browsers (most importantly IE), but just doesn't appear in an HTA? Am I going to need to find a different way to inject a progress bar?

```
<html>
<head><title>Generic Title</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
    ID="planner"
    APPLICATIONNAME="Progress Bar Test"
    SCROLL="no"
    SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
    WINDOWSTATE="auto"
    CAPTION="yes"
    BORDER="thin"
    BORDERSTYLE="raised"
>
</head>

<body>
<progress value="22" max="100"></progress>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're probably running in IE8 mode.

Comment: I have <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9"> and have tested a few other CSS3 objects that have worked fine (rounded borders and such). Unless I'm missing something else?

Answer (score 1):

Well it wasn't an IE8 compatibility, but you did help me answer it since I didn't realize IE9's HTML5 support is pretty terrible as well. I updated to IE=11 instead and it seems to work fine now.

Thanks!